# Laravel send composite primary key in a Form

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-query-builder

Hi i have a table **Classe** with composite primary key my problem is when i try to delete,update or show a row of my table for exemple for Delete :

Classe View :

```
{!!Form::open(array('route'=>['class.destroy',$cl->id1,$cl->id2],'method'=>'DELETE'))!!}
{!!Form::button('Delete',['class'=>'btn btn-danger','type'=>'submit'])!!}
{!!Form::close()!!}
```

ClasseController

```
public function destroy(Classe $classe)
    {
        $classe->delete();
        return redirect()->route('class.index')->with('message','successufuly deleted');
    }
```

when i click on delete i return the message **successufuly deleted** but the row still exist in the table , i tried to pass all the **$cl** using

```
{!!Form::open(array('route'=>['class.destroy',$cl],'method'=>'DELETE'))!!}
```

but it show an error :

***RouteCollection->methodNotAllowed(array('GET', 'HEAD', 'POST')) in RouteCollection.php line 205***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eloquent doesn't support composite primary keys, so you can add your own route to another method of your controller that will recive two parameters ($cl->id1,$cl->id2), then find you instance model with these keys and do the delete.

Comment: Ok thnk u so much :)